# Grandchild Term Things Grandfather Term is It's Parent

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy

I've got the following product categories:

> Pricing Tagging
>
> > Monarch Supplies
> >
> > > Labels

But when I do

```
get_term( $labels_id );
```

It says that it's parent is the Pricing Tagging id, not Monarch Supplies.

How can I get just the sub categories of pricing tagging excluding sub-sub-categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) and the [`parent`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) argument.

> 'parent' (int|string) Parent term ID to retrieve direct-child terms
>   of.

```
$parent_term_id     = 123;
$direct_child_terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => '[taxonomy]',
    'parent'   => $parent_term_id,
) );
```

Don't forget to replace `[taxonomy]` with whatever the taxonomy is; e.g., `post_tag`, `product_cat`, etc. *Additional arguments for further customization [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/).*